# Fixed and free axis + repated use of data using ggplot facet _wrap?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot below in ggplot. Not quite sure how to

1) build a data set so I can call it twice (once on the left for all values, and once on the right for small values)?

2) have the panels on the right with fixed axis limits whilst those on the left are free?

```
set.seed(1)
xx1<-c(rnorm(100, 10, 10), rnorm(100, 1, 1))
yy1<-c(rnorm(100, 10, 10), rnorm(100, 1, 1))
xx2<-c(rnorm(100, 10, 10), rnorm(100, 1, 1))
yy2<-c(rnorm(100, 10, 10), rnorm(100, 1, 1))
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=rep(2,4))
plot(xx1, yy1, main="First Period, All")
plot(xx1, yy1, xlim=c(-2,4), ylim=c(-2,4), main="First Period, Small")
plot(xx2, yy2, main="Second Period, All")
plot(xx2, yy2, xlim=c(-2,4), ylim=c(-2,4), main="Second Period, Small")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be acceptable?

```
d1 <- data.frame(Group = rep(c('First Period, All', 'First Period, Small'),
                             each = 200),
                 x = xx1,
                 y = yy1)
d2 <- data.frame(Group = rep(c('Second Period, All', 'Second Period, Small'),
                             each = 200),
                 x = xx2,
                 y = yy2)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
```

Edit - Provide a plot with no background with theme_bw()

```
g1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 
  labs(title = 'First Period, All', x='', y='') +
  theme_bw()
g2 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(-2, 4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(-2, 4)) +
  labs(title = 'First Period, Small', , x='', y='') +
  theme_bw()
g3 <- ggplot(d2, aes(x=x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'Second Period, All', x='', y='') +
  theme_bw()
g4 <- ggplot(d2, aes(x=x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(-2, 4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(-2, 4)) +
  labs(title = 'Second Period, Small', x='', y='') +
  theme_bw()

grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, g4)
```

[image: plot with grid.arrange()]

Comment: great! thanks, never knew about the gridExtra package.

Comment: @gjabel yes gridExtra in nice and provide a simple way to do this.

Comment: does it allow axis labels to be shared across panels, as is the case in `facet_wrap`?

Comment: @gjabel Sorry but by 'labels to be shared' you mean?

Comment: I don't think you can do it (control scales for each plot) with faceting.